# Building Examine (lucene.net) index with comma separated list of IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, lucene.net

I have an Umbraco website that is using Examine search which is based on lucene.net. I am pretty much trying to do exactly what is described in the following article:

[Querying against a comma separated list of IDs with Examine and Lucene.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124183/querying-against-a-comma-separated-list-of-ids-with-examine-and-lucene-net)

The problem I have is when I am trying to create the index using the following code:

```
// Loop through articles
        foreach (var a in articles)
        {
            yield return new SimpleDataSet()
            {
                NodeDefinition = new Examine.IndexedNode()
                {
                    NodeId = a.Id,
                    Type = "Article"

                },
                RowData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"Name", a.Name},
                    {"Url", a.NiceUrl},
                    {"Category", "1234"},
                    {"Category", "5678"}
                }
            };
        }
```

I am receiving the following error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Comment: Im no expert on Examine but it looks like Lucene is wrapped very restictively, in native Lucene you have the options to add muliple values to a single field and that sounds what you are looking for.

Comment: @miracledev Judging by the answer in the post I linked to in my question it would seem as if it is possible in Examine. Do you know how you create an index in Lucene with multiple values to a single field? Maybe that may point me in the right direction

Comment: @tfletch Yes, basically that is what rae1n is showing you in his answer. I answered with a full example too that is runnable in a Console application with Lucene.NET nuget package added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example of doing it in lucene, however as said Examine seems to limit the flexiblity by having input in a Dictionary. However changing examine to handle it should be simple.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Analyzer analyser = new StandardAnalyzer (Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);
        Directory dir = new RAMDirectory ();

        using (IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter (dir, analyser, Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)) {

            Document doc1 = new Document ();
            doc1.Add (new Field("title", "multivalued", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc1.Add (new Field("multival", "val1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc1.Add (new Field("multival", "val2", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            iw.AddDocument (doc1);
            Document doc2 = new Document ();
            doc2.Add (new Field("title", "singlevalued", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc2.Add (new Field("multival", "val1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));        
            iw.AddDocument (doc2);
        }

        using (Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher (dir, true)) {
            var q1 = new TermQuery (new Term ("multival", "val1"));
            var q1result = searcher.Search (q1, 1000);

            //Will print "Found 2 documents"
            Console.WriteLine ("Found {0} documents", q1result.TotalHits);

            var q2 = new TermQuery (new Term ("multival", "val2"));
            var q2result = searcher.Search (q2, 1000);
            //Will print "Found 1 documents"
            Console.WriteLine ("Found {0} documents", q2result.TotalHits);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have now rewritten my search to use Lucene.net instead of using Examine and implemented code similar to above.

Answer (score 2):

The next version of Examine (v2) will support this properly, with any luck that might be out within a couple months but that's really just dependent on how much time we get.

In the meantime, you could use the DocumentWriting event on your indexer which gives you direct access to the Lucene Document, then you can index however you like. So you could initially have a comma separated list of ids for your categories and during this event you could split them and add them as individual values in Lucene.

Comment: It's pretty easy to use the DocumentWriting event to index multivalued fields. I have an example at http://www.alexlindgren.com/archive/using-umbraco-examine-for-optimizing-page-performance/

Comment: Yup, you will also need to use the `GetValues` method on the search result to get all of the values stored separately in a single field: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Examine/blob/dev/Projects/Examine/SearchResult.cs#L30

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is a restriction of .NET's `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class as mentioned by @DavidH. The restriction is inherited from Examine's `SimpleDataSet` class, which by looking at the [source](http://examine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Projects/Examine/LuceneEngine/SimpleDataSet.cs) only allows `Dictionary<string, string>` as a way of adding row data to a document.

However, a Lucene `Document` *does* allow you to add multiple fields with the same name as mentioned on the linked question:

```
using Lucene.Net.Documents;

var document = new Document();
document.Add(CreateField("Id", a.Id));
document.Add(CreateField("Name", a.Name));
document.Add(CreateField("Url", a.NiceUrl));        
document.Add(CreateField("Category", "1234"));    
document.Add(CreateField("Category", "5678"));    

...

private Field CreateField(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    return new Field(
        fieldName, 
        fieldValue, 
        Field.Store.YES, 
        Field.Index.ANALYZED);
}
```

Although not as convenient as Examine's API, using Lucene natively is a lot more flexible for these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary keys must be unique, and this is not specific to Lucene but instead to the .NET `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class. One possible option is to pipe delimit the values under one "Category" dictionary key, and then split on the pipe character to parse them out:

```
RowData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"Name", a.Name},
    {"Url", a.NiceUrl},
    {"Category", "1234|5678"}
}
```

You could then use `string.Split` on the pipe character '|' to parse them back out.

Comment: Hi David, this is exactly what I was trying to avoid for speed reasons. The category source is already a comma separated list but I wanted to be able to search on the category field without having to do any conversion as detailed in the link on my question. Judging by the answer to question I linked to, this is possible but obviously not using the method that I have because of what you said about the dictionary class. Unfortunately the answer in the question I linked to didn't provide details as to how they got the category data into the Examine (lucene) index.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's where my knowledge of Lucene stops as well. Sorry.