# Can I run a Lucene query against a field with character-separated integers?

Tags: asp.net, lucene, content-management-system

I am working within an ASP.NET CMS [cms](/questions/tagged/cms) which uses an abstraction of Lucene.NET to power searches. It unfortunately doesn't offer me a lot of control over how these indexes are built.

I do however have full control over the code which queries this index. I can construct my own queries using [Lucene query parser syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html). I also have a choice of analyzers.

What I have is a text field which contains a list of integer IDs separated by semi-colons. If I was constructing my index documents manually I'd be able to duplicate field names (ref. [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796975/building-examine-lucene-net-index-with-comma-separated-list-of-ids)). But I don't have that luxury.

So say I have 2 index documents. The first has field `test` with value `1,5,94` and the second has field `test` with value `4,95,555`. Is it in any way possible for me to construct a query parser string that will only return the first document when searching for all instances of `5` in field `test`?

Comment: Ideally, you would want to change how the field is being indexed.  You say you have some control over analysis.  Are you able to impact the *index-time* analysis at all?  Or if not, a slightly hacky approach might be to replace commas with spaces (numbers separated by commas are a special case that isn't tokenized in the StandardAnalyzer).

Comment: I've tried your second suggestion and this works exactly as I hoped. Thank you very much for your help.